# Configuring Checkstyle to ignore generic warnings

Tags: java, generics, javadoc, checkstyle, suppress-warnings

I'm working on a project and using checkstyle to validate the javadocs for the project. I do not want any checkstyle javadoc warnings.

However checkstyle is giving me the following unwanted warning to do with generics:

> Expected @param tag for '< T > '.

Is there a way I can turn off or suppress this particular warning?

The only way that I have come across doing this is suppressing warnings for a particular line which I do not wish to do.

Anyone know a way of configuring checkstyle to ignore generic warnings?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure this behavior of the [JavadocType](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html#JavadocType) check by setting the `allowMissingParamTags` property to `true` like so:

```xml
<module name="JavadocType">
    <property name="allowMissingParamTags" value="true"/>
</module>
```

On my version of the Eclipse checkstyle plugin (5.6.0.201209221626), this option is somehow not present in the GUI (bug?), but it can be set by directly editing the XML.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It turns out that I didn't need to do this as I wanted to see the errors after all.

But just out of curiosity, if I did it like you suggest will that not turn off warnings for all missing Javadoc tags? I would have still wanted to see all other missing param tags. Just not the generic ones.
Do you understand where I am coming from? Perhaps this isn't possible?

Comment: @Kevin Yes, this will only affect your generic type params, because it's set on the *JavadocType* check, which knows no other params. *JavadocMethod* is not affected (which might be a "problem" if you have methods with generic params).